# double free or corruption error on Unix system

Tags: c++, unix, destructor

I am getting this message after running my program on Unix system:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./anal: double free or corruption (fasttop):
```

On windows it is working fine. I had already find that it my be caused by destructor because of using insert and =. probably the error is in this line:

```
ret = trigrams.insert ( pair<string,int>(tempStr,1) );
```

But my question is how to resolve it? I need to create copy of both map and iterator? I thin it would be waste of memory. Should i overload the operator "=" to create a copy, but how? I am working usually with java so it is quite wired for me.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
map<string,int> trigrams;
pair<map<string,int>::iterator,bool> ret;
map<string,int>::iterator it;
char tmp[3];
FILE *fp = fopen ("new.txt" , "r");
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
size_t fileSize = ftell(fp);
cout<<fileSize<<"\n";
ifstream is("new.txt");
string tempStr;
char c;
int i=0;
it = trigrams.begin(); 
#pragma omp parallel for default(shared) shared(trigrams, c, it, ret)  private(i)   
for(i=0; i<=fileSize;i++)          
{
    if((i%3)==0&&(i!=0)){
        tempStr = tmp;  
        tempStr = tempStr.substr(0,3);
        ret = trigrams.insert ( pair<string,int>(tempStr,1) );
        if (ret.second==false) {
            trigrams[tempStr] += 1;
        }
    }
    c = is.get();
    if(c != '\n')          
        tmp[i%3]=c;
}
is.close();            
ofstream file;
file.open ("new3.txt");
for (it=trigrams.begin(); it!=trigrams.end(); ++it){
    file <<it->first<<"  "<< it->second<<"\n";


}
file.close();
return 0;
}
```

And here is simple program which is working:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
map<int,string> trigrams;
pair<map<int,string>::iterator,bool> ret;
map<int, string>::iterator it;
it = trigrams.begin(); 
for(int i=0; i<=100;i++)          
{
    ret = trigrams.insert ( pair<int, string>(i, "tempStr") );
    it++;
}
for (it=trigrams.begin(); it!=trigrams.end(); ++it){
    cout <<it->first<<"  "<< it->second<<"\n";


}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: Use `std::make_pair` instead of explicitly specifying the template arguments.

Comment: See [this blog post](http://alschwalm.com/blog/2014/01/23/Template-argument-deduction-CPP.html) for more about `std::make_pair`.  Also, consider using Valgrind to help nail down exactly where the double-free is coming from.

Comment: can you isolate the problem? I see a junk of code with no connection. like `it = trigrams.begin();` but you're do nothing with it, or `c = is.get()` when types of `c`, `is` and `get` is unknown...

Comment: Thanks for answers. I had just show a part of application which in my opinion caused a problem. Now i have edited first post to show all problem. I am not sure if i understand why do i need to put it into template classes as it was shown in first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have a race condition here - you simultaneously trying to insert values to a map from different threads, and map is not thread-safe in C++. Races can lead to many nasty things, including double free. The worst thing is that program behavior becomes very random and that may be the reason why it works fine on windows.

Comment: Have You got nay ideas how to correct it? I would like to use it for openmp paralellization later... Error is being called of course without openmp.

Comment: Hm, I've noticed one more thing - strings in c++ are null-terminated and so tempStr = tmp; may lead to crash. You can probably write char tmp[4] = {}; to fix it.

Comment: You mean tmp should be a char array? It is now... Or you mean map should contains <char[],int>?

Comment: I mean that tmp should be at least 4 chars long, and have 0 at the end of it. just replace char tmp[3]; to char tmp[4] = {};

Comment: Thank you, but it did not help. Actually these is our school server i choose another one and it is working fine over there... I will try to find out later what was wrong with those one.